# Finding functions to prove termination of a specific rewrite system.

Tags: functions, discrete-mathematics

I am trying to prove the termination of some rewrite system by defining a size function for the terms. We know that a rewrite system terminates if the size of the terms are increasing after every rewrite step.

In the system I have elements $n$ and $s$ and functions $a$ and $r$, we have $l$ as an arbitrary combination the functions applied on the elements, we also call $l$ an expression. The rewrite system is

$$ \begin{align*} 
a(n,l) & \rightarrow l \\ 
a(l,n) & \rightarrow l \\
a(a(l_1,l_2),l_3) &\rightarrow a(l_1,a(l_2,l_3)) \\
r(n) &\rightarrow n \\ 
r(s) &\rightarrow s \\
r(a(l_1,l_2)) & \rightarrow a(r(l_1),r(l_2))\\
r(r(l)) & \rightarrow l
\end{align*}$$

I want to make a size function to proof the termination of the rewrite system. We know that the rewrite system will terminate if we can find a size function such that for every rewrite rule holds that $expr_1 \rightarrow expr_2 \Rightarrow size (expr_2) \lt size (expr_1)$.

We can define the size function for $n$ and $s$ as $size(n) =1 $ and $size(s) =1$, but we also want to define a size function for $size(a(l_1,l_2)$ and $size(r(l))$. The hard part is to chose this $size$ function right for the third and last two rewrite rules.

To reduce this problem, we can also say that we want to find two functions $f_1: \mathbb{N} \rightarrow \mathbb{N} $ and $f_2: \mathbb{N} \rightarrow \mathbb{N} \rightarrow \mathbb{N}$ where $0 \not\in \mathbb{N}$.

Where we want that for all $n,m,p \in \mathbb{N}$ that,

1. $n \lt f_1 ( f_1 (n) )$
2. $f_2(n , f_2(m, p) ) \lt f_2(f_2(n, m),p)$
3. $f_2( f_1 ( n) , f_1(m)) \lt f_1 ( f_2(n, m)) $

To satisfy the first two conditions we can for example chose $$ f_1(n) = n + 1 $$ and $$ f_2(n,m) = 2n + m + 1,$$

but I can not come up with something that also satisfy the third condition. I have tried to add some squares, but that did not helped me.

Does anyone have an idea for a function that would work, or have a prove that there does not exists such functions? I hope someone can help me out.

Comment: You just want any pair of functions that works? At the beginning, it sounded like you had a specific termination system in mind.

Comment: Yes, I have a specific rewrite system in mind. I hope that I made my post more clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're close. $f_1(n)=2n$ works with your $f_2(n,m) = 2n+m+1$. Intuitively this is because without the extra $+1$ term, there's no longer a bonus by having that term in both arguments of $f_2$. Formally:
$$2(2n)+(2m)+1 < 2(2n+m+1).$$
Since $0$ is not in your natural numbers, $f_1$ satisfies the first condition as well, and you've already calculated the second condition. (But if needed, we can modify to work with zero by conjugating with $k\mapsto k+1$)

Comment: Thank you for your response. Unfortunately I made a mistake in the question. In the right hand side of the third equation, the n and m had to be the other way around.

Comment: (I apologize for the tone of my earlier comment.) While I'm sorry this didn't help you out, on MSE it is generally considered rude to change your Question in a way that invalidates an existing Answer.

Comment: I'm sorry, I did not want to be rude. I undid changed of the question. It is new for me to post questions here.

Comment: Yeah, I figured. No hard feelings :)